# CSS order of precedence

Tags: css, stylesheet, operator-precedence

I have a question on stylesheet order of precedence. Is there a 6th one ? ***user agent important declarations***. If so what is it order of precedence?

Already looked at this w3.org , https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade , 
But it has mentioned only 5 different sources

1.) user agent declarations
2.) user normal declarations
3.) author normal declarations
4.) author important declarations
5.) user important declarations

I have seen the 6th one in a certification question. But couldn't find the information on it.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: What's the difference between the 5th and 6th you mention?

Comment: 5th is user specified settings , 6th one is user agent (browser) settings, similar to 1st one. But 1st one is normal, not important.

Comment: If important is stronger then regular, of course user important is stronger then user regular. Any more questions I may have missed?

Answer (score 5):

**MDN** have a better explanation, hope it helps.

> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade
>
> [image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @ajeshrkurup no prob, glad to help :D